# Close QMenuBar item automatically

Tags: qt, qmenu, qmenubar

I need to know if there is a way to close an opened `QMenuBarItem` in Qt.
I mean, if I Open a Menu, I want a `QTimer` to be able to close the `QMenuBar` after some time.

I am starting a `QTimer` when I click a menu (like "File"), and in the `QTimer`'s `timeout()` slot I am using the next code:

```
menubar->actions()[0]->menu()->close();
```

Where `menubar->actions()[0]` is the "File" menu.

I have been searching without success and I really need to close the menu automatically.

I really appreciate your help and your time.
Thanks in advance.

*****EDIT

You must use `menubar.setActiveAction(NULL)`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `QWidget::hide()` instead of `QWidget::close()`.